# Collection View in View Controller Does Not Display My Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I'm just 1 week old to iOS, currently my app contains of a view controller with collection view inside, the collection view will be displaying the image which retrieve from the URL.

But my collection view will not display any image when running the app, I tried to NSLog the indexPath and it did showed the index in console.

Here is my .h file: http://pastebin.com/Vv6ib66R, and .m file: http://pastebin.com/QH48M5QB

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
```

delegate method for the collection view?

Comment: Hi, nope I didn't implement this method as I don't have any section for my collection view, even I tried implement it but there is still not output as well.